# Why were the throne room windows covered with a red curtain?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

[image]

In *The Last Jedi*, Kylo Ren took Rey to Snoke's throne room, which ended up with them fighting against the Praetorian Guards. In the heat of the battle, a guard's electro-chain weapon was thrown at the large red curtain on the background, setting it on fire. As the curtain burned down it revealed the huge screen windows of the Supremacy.

What was the original purpose of this curtain? Why were the windows covered with it?

Comment: Because it looks *awesome*.

Comment: Snoke is extremely susceptible to sunburn.

Comment: He doesn't want the mynocks to see him.

Answer (score 10):

In-Universe, the [Last Jedi Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) notes that the curtains serve as camouflage for Snoke's Praetorian Guard, his literal last-line-of-defence against assassination attempts, but one that is largely hidden from guests.

> *Eight Prateorians flank Snoke's throne, **their red armour blending into
> the curtain that surrounds the chamber.** They stand as implacable
> unmoving sentinels, but should any hostility surface from Snoke's rare
> invited guests, they snap instantly into combat stances.*

---

Out-of-universe there's a couple of reasons behind this bold visual choice. The director wanted to preserve the red and white motif inspired by the planet Crait

> **StarWars.com:** *All the posters have this red-and-white motif. You can see it carried through in the footage we’ve seen in the teasers
> and trailers. It’s really unique. I don’t think any of the other films
> had this specific a look with bold, clean colors. Where did that come
> from?*
>
> **Rian Johnson:** It was something that developed… It went back to the
> script, I guess. The idea for Crait, very early on, was a visual idea
> that was there even before I started writing the script. Snoke’s
> throne room, which is the other big red environment, was something I
> had that I was fixated on. The idea of this theatrical space. Snoke
> uses theatricality, and so it’s this very striking, graphic, bold
> space, and red felt right to me for that space, as well. It’s probably
> a combination of me just liking bold, graphic design like that, and
> the natural development of it. Red just felt right for this middle
> chapter. It felt kind of dangerous.
>
> <sub><sup>[“WE HAD SUCH A GREAT TIME”: RIAN JOHNSON ON THE PATH TO STAR WARS: THE LAST JEDI](http://www.starwars.com/news/we-had-such-a-great-time-rian-johnson-on-the-path-to-star-wars-the-last-jedi)</sup></sub>

Production Designer Rick Heinrichs says that he and Rian Johnson were inspired by a piece of original (unused) Ralph McQuarrie concept art; **Vader in the Emperor's Throne Room**

> **Rick Heinrichs (Production Designer):** It was one of the earliest
> sequences that we discussed…we explored many different looks and feels
> to it, and it all came back to his desire to put across a ceremonial
> environment for the Supreme Leader to reign from. That was incredibly
> important, that the environment support the concept of Snoke at the
> pinnacle of – at the knife-edge, if you will – of the First Order. One
> of the earliest inspirations I can remember from this, I went through
> all the archives that I could get my hands on at Skywalker Ranch, and
> there was this great image that Ralph McQuarrie had painted. It was
> actually of Darth Vader in a throne room. And it wasn’t right in terms
> of the practical aspect of it – it was literally like a medieval
> throne room with flames all around him – but the idea of creating a
> metaphorical hell with the use of the red color, but making it as
> elegant as possible, that coincides with the ethos of the First Order
> and the black, the reflectivity, and the hard, sharp, almost
> crystalline inhuman shapes that are a part of that.
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Star Wars: The Last Jedi’: The Definitive Oral History of the Lightsaber Battle in Snoke’s Throne Room](http://www.slashfilm.com/the-last-jedi-lightsaber-battle/)</sup></sub>

[image]

It also serves (as the curtain burns) to underline that the First Order is built on ***image over substance.***

> **Heinrichs:** *I think that as we discussed what happens in the set over
> the course of it, the initial strong red color and how red evolves
> over the course of the scene has everything to do with the action that
> happens within it. So yes, we had an incredibly striking visual color
> that seems to override the entire scene that, as things progress and
> the fighting ensues and that burns down, it reveals the black void
> beyond. **It underlines the ceremonial face that Snoke is putting on for
> anyone who happens to come before him.***
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Star Wars: The Last Jedi’: The Definitive Oral History of the Lightsaber Battle in Snoke’s Throne Room](http://www.slashfilm.com/the-last-jedi-lightsaber-battle/3/)</sup></sub>

Comment: it's also an interesting allusion to two of the most well known curtain destroyed situations in culture. 1) The Wizard of Oz's curtain being torn down to reveal his humanity / weakness 2) from the Bible - the curtain in the temple being destoryed at the crucifixion

Comment: I think that first quote means that the armour was chosen to blend into the curtains, not the other way around.  But in-universe there doesn't need to be any particular reason other than "Snoke liked it that way".

Comment: @HarryJohnston - We know that the armour was chosen because of its connection (and similarity) with the Emperor's Imperial guards. You're right that it might just have been a coincidence. We've not got anything more to go on then that quote. Perhaps we'll get more in the novelisations when they land in March